# How to convert array object to arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I have a class like this:

```
Enum = function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        var k= arguments[i];
        this[k] = i;
    }
    Object.freeze(this);
};
```

To create an enum of string, usually I just call :
var options = new Enum("EAT","DRINK","SLEEP"); // many arguments

If I have an array of arguments already which stored in a variable. 
`Ex: var arg_array = ["EAT","DRINK","SLEEP"]`, 
how could I pass it to new Enum(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var a = {};
Enum.apply(a, ["EAT","DRINK","SLEEP"]);
```

will give you:

```
{
  "EAT": 0,
  "DRINK": 1,
  "SLEEP": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just take an array as argument for the constructor and use it, as you did, with the arguments array:

```
Enum = function(arr) {
    if(arr){
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            var k= arr[i];
            this[k] = i;
        }
    }
    Object.freeze(this);
};
```

then just hand over the array when you create your enum:

```
var options = new Enum(arg_array);
```